# Shopify: How can I handle an uninstall followed by an instant re-install?

Tags: shopify

I've recently had the case that a user un-installed my Shopify app and instantly re-installed it. This caused a problem because I store all my users in a DB table.

Login/Installing works as follows:

1. The user tells me his shop URL
2. I forward the user to
   example.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize where access is granted
   to my app
3. I check if that shop URL is already stored in my local
   user DB

   - If not: I request a permanent access token and forward the
     user to the plan selection page
   - If yes: I get the stored permanent access token from the user DB and log the user into my app

Uninstalling:

1. The user uninstalls my app in his Shopify backend
2. Shopify sends a webhook to my app
3. I remove that user's data from the user DB

The problem is that the webhooks are sometimes delayed. If an user uninstalls and instantly re-installs, my app will think the install is a login attempt, and will use the now invalid access token stored in the user DB.

I figured I could just check if the redirection from the authorization page contains a temporary access token, and if yes, it would be a new installation, but it seems the access token is returned even if the app has already been installed.

So my question is: How can I handle instant re-installation gracefully? Surely there's something that I'm overlooking, there can't be such a huge "logic bug" in the Shopify API?

Comment: Related question https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/508

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've had this problem with my apps as well lately. Webhooks only started getting delayed in the last 2 months, and I'd be surprised if most apps out there weren't suffering from this regression bug now.

The way I deal with it is - when the user is redirected to the app and the old db object/token is still present in the database, try calling a dummy API call to the Shopify API (something like get shop details) with the token you have. If you get a 403 Unauthorized response, invalidate the user session and refresh the stored token.

Another problem is that after a minute or two when the original uninstall webhook does fire, do the same procedure - check for a 403 response. If you **DON'T** get a 403, then you know that the webhook is old and shouldn't be acted upon, because if you get a 200 OK it means that your token is good and that the app is still installed.

It's a bit convoluted and it added a fair bit of code to my apps, but it's the only thing I could think of on a short notice - because merchants do uninstall/re-install quickly fairly often.

Comment: Wow, very clever solution, didn't even think of that! By the way, there was am [official announcement from Shopify about the delay](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/announce-webhooks-don%E2%80%99t-depend-on-their-real-timey-ness-115431). I will keep this question opened for a few more days, perhaps somebody form Shopify could clarify that there really isn't another way to do this?

Comment: Seems that this is indeed the way to go. I have tried it and it works perfectly. I do have to say it feels a bit hacky but I guess that's what you get for working with an API that changes rapidly. :)

Comment: The correct code is 401 for an Unauthorized response. https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/response-status-codes