# Shopify: getting an access token through the ShopifyAPI in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

After a customer deinstalls an app, I have to get rid of some data in the database.

In the following post it is stated that you get a different token from a shop, when the customer reinstalls an app. My problem is that I do not know what to call in the Rails ShopifyAPI to get this token, in order to save it and then compare it everytime. I am using the ShopifyApp Gem which uses the the ShopifyAPI gem. Is there a method for this?

[Shopify: How to delete database entry fast after uninstall web-hook response, so the merchant uninstall and re-install quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686977/shopify-how-to-delete-database-entry-fast-after-uninstall-web-hook-response-so?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the app/uninstall webhook to remove all their data from the shop. There is no API to call to get a token.

If a shop tries to use your App with no entry in your database, you would initiate the oAuth sequence to get a new token. That is the only way to do it.